# win form webBrowser menu

Tags: javascript, winforms, events, click, browser

I created a WebBrowser winform application and and menu strip at the top of it. 
i want to use the javascript button inside the html viewr (WebBrowser) from winform menu strip

here is the my web application menu

```
<a href="javascript:findPatient('ID');"   class="navitem">Patient ID</a>
```

how do i create a click event for this href="javascript:findPatient('ID');"
some time i also need onclick whic is in my web application

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cb_top' onclick='toggleFrame(1)' checked />
```

how to i create a click event for this,
please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the methodology, you seem to be a good enough coder to tweak it to your situation:

```
Private Function ClickSubmitButton()

        Dim theButton As HtmlElement

        Try

            ' Link the ID from the web form to the Button var
            theButton = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton")

            ' Now do the actual click.
            theButton.InvokeMember("click")
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return False

        End Try

    End Function
```